# View changes to group docs on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, you can add docs to groups that anyone in the group can edit. Is it possible to view the changes that each person made?

Answer (score 1):

No, as of now, Facebook does not has any such option.

Also, the Facebook API does not allows interaction with groups, so you can't add this feature in Facebook on your own.

You can always switch to Google Docs or Google Drive for such needs.